# Nested Vertical Scroll vs Accordion

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

I have this problem.
I need to display all of the the following elements (cannot do contextual for lack of resources) as this is an administrative platform for employees only.:[image]

Each user license which uses a USB hardware key displays all of these properties:

A client can have multiple dongles/licenses, but they probably won't. I chose to create an accordion like material design to expand/collapse.

My question is , what is the usability for a long accordion vs scroll? Example of card with scroll from Hubspot Free CRM:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling comes into play when you wanna prevent display of unnecessary data(as in the case of Hubspot) and give the user free hand to jump to next part of information in the main modal.

So it depends on the importance of the data you want to display.

Comment: Can you expand on this please? It's not very clear. Are you suggesting that a scroll is preferrable to accordion in this situation? If so - please elaborate on your reasoning.

Comment: In This situation user needs to check the profile data(which has more importance), so it won't be feasible to put scroll in the data panels. Hence, it is better user uses the main modal scrolling.